# GUI software to compress and merge PDFs

Tags: open-source, pdf, file-compression, file-merging

[Compress PDF](http://smallpdf.com/compress-pdf) and [Merge PDF](http://smallpdf.com/merge-pdf) are fantastically easy to use. I would highly recommend them had it not been because I cannot guarantee who has access to the data.

So is there free (as in freedom) software that I can install, which does the same?

I know of PDFTK, but I am interested in a web frontend similar to the above (Linux or Windows is fine), or at the very least a free (as in freedom) software Windows tool that is just as easy to use.

**Note**: My users are naïve Microsoft Windows users. So cmdline for Linux is unfortunately not usable.

Comment: What do you find hard to use about pfdtk? The free, "server", edition is super easy to use from the command line and can be hidden behind a web interface, (and often is).

Comment: I was about to recommend ghostscript, but it lacks a fancy UI.

Comment: So you are looking for a web application? Would be useful to tell in the title.

Comment: Not necessarily: As I mentioned in the answer I installed 'PDF Split and Merge' which solves the merging. The answer was deleted by http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/46/undo so unfortunately you cannot see it. Complain to Undo.

Comment: ImageMagick can do merging, but I don't know of it can compress it...

Comment: I use free tools from https://pdfsam.org and https://www.pdfill.com.  They're both great.  PDF SAM is easier to use since it has just the basic functions. 
PDFill is worth exploring if you need more tools.  I'm sorry but I don't think they're open source, however.

Comment: [PDF24 Creator](https://alternativeto.net/software/pdf24-creator/) worked for me like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to merge my 10 bank statements into a single PDF file, but it was quite risky to upload these documents to server for combining them. I found a free Windows based PDF split and merge application which helped me to do the same.  Free software download is available here: http://www.systotech.com/pdf-split-and-merge.aspx

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting, but I cannot find the source code or the license. Are you sure it is free (as in freedom) software - and not just gratis? If you cannot check the source code for back doors, Snowden has shown that it is not trustworthy software - even when coming from vendors like Google and Microsoft (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRISM_(surveillance_program) for an example where Google, Microsoft, and others have put in back doors in their software without telling their users). For now I will stay with http://www.pdfsam.org/

Comment: That domain is dead (for sale)

Comment: Domain is still for sale over a year later.  Doesn't look like it's coming back.

Answer (score 0):

For merging I have until recently used [PDF Split and Merge](http://www.pdfsam.org)

But [PDF-Arranger](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger/releases) is even more smooth, because you can split/merge/rotate and visually arrange in one go.

It still does not solve the compress issue.